# Where is my new created HTML file

Tags: amazon-web-services, phpexcel, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm using PHPexcel on beanstalk. One of PHPexcel features is the ability to transform HTML tables into Excel sheets. In order to do that it first creates a proper HTML document and then extracts the table from it. Using it on my hosted server I could easily spot the new created HTML file (using a client) on my server.

Recently I moved my app to aws beanstalk and now I'm getting all sort of errors. In order to further inspect the errors I have to locate the HTML file that PHPexcel is creating but I can't find it. Is it stored in S3 buckets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's going to be on the EC2 server (or one of the EC2 servers) managed by Elastic Beanstalk. You probably need to `ssh` into the server (or servers) and find it. I'm not sure why you would think it would be on S3, but there is no AWS  "magic" that automatically moves files your app creates on the server to an S3 bucket.

Comment: The problem was that my PHPexcel script was using PHP `file_put_contents` to put content in to a file I created dynamicly. The file path of that last file was wrong. I fixed the path and now it's working again